# How to show coordinates label (x,y) with ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, charts

I wanna know if there's a way to plot the coordinate "(x,y)" of the points in the data frame ?

This is the current code.

```
library(ggplot2)

x <- c(4,3,5,8,2,5,6,3,1)
y <- c(3,4,2,1,7,1,2,6,3)
df <- data.frame(x,y)
ggplot(data=df, mapping =  aes(x=x, y= y)) + geom_point()+ 
  geom_segment(aes(x=4, xend= x, y = 3, yend = y),col="red")
```

Which plot the below graphic.

[image]

A good answer would be the graphic with the coordinate "(x,y)" plotted on graph and the code explained to do it.

Answer (score 4):

You can do this easily using `geom_text()` or `geom_label()`. Here I've used `nudge_y` to show the coordinates slightly above the plotted points instead of directly on top of them. I've also used `paste0()` to create the text for the labels in the format specified.

```r
library(ggplot2)

df <- data.frame(
  x = c(4, 3, 5, 8, 2, 5, 6, 3, 1),
  y = c(3, 4, 2, 1, 7, 1, 2, 6, 3) 
)

ggplot(df, aes(x, y)) + 
  geom_point() + 
  geom_segment(aes(x = 4, xend = x, y = 3, yend = y), colour = "red") +
  geom_text(aes(label = paste0("(", x, ", ", y, ")")), nudge_y = 0.2)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2024-03-13 with [reprex v2.1.0](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>